# DC's on separate sites, VPN connection, gateway change - can't see each other

Tags: vpn, domain-controller, gateway

Ok I had a working setup and I know what the issue is but just asking if simple way to fix. Two offices each with DC on different IP ranges, 160.0.1.x and 160.0.2.x. The VPN goes to a router 160.0.1.254 in main office. The gateway on the DC in that office used to be 160.0.1.254 but has now changed to 160.0.1.253.
Now the two DC's cannot see each other, no ping, trust etc obviously because I have changed the gateway. I am trying to get a 4 port WAN router so all my connections (WAN) go out of single router (254) but for now is there any fix so I can get the two DC to see each other?.

Thanks

Paul,

Comment: Ok, so just to confirm, the original vpn and router still exist, but you have pointed the server at a different router

Comment: Yes. 

The DC originally using 254 is now on 253. Each router has 2 ports. The 254 router now gives a separate connections to 2 offices - remote desktop. The DC is also the email server, bound to a specific IP. This connection was moved off 254 to 253.

Paul,

Comment: If there is still a vpn present on the 254 router to the 160.0.2.x subnet then try adding the following route to the dc with the 253 gateway `route add 160.0.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 160.0.1.254` see if you can then ping the other dc from that dc

Comment: I made certain assumptions about subnets in that comment, if it resolves the issue I will clarify in an answer

Comment: Ok have to be careful here. The 160.0.2.0 subnet connects through a VPN wan connection on the 254 router. The connection is to allow remote users to login in to a Citrix Server which is set on 160.0.1.254 gateway. Adding a route to the DC  - the one with the 160.0.1.253 gateway wont cause an issue will it?

Comment: From the information you have given me I can't see it causing an issue

Comment: Ok. I would assume this will only work one way from the DC who's routing table I am changing?

Comment: Yes that is correct